# PC hangs AFTER being idle for a longer time - i5-8600K / RX 590 / B360M PRO-VDH

Tags: freeze

The problem is that the PC hangs AFTER being idle for a longer time, like 4 hours. It doesn't hang while being idle, just moments after I turn my monitor on. Sometimes it takes a second, sometimes a few minutes after powering on the screen. I know for sure that it hanged when starting a video playback in my browser Vivaldi, so I think it may be GPU related. Other times, it hangs more randomly, like loading some app. When it hangs, the screen turns to some solid color, like orange, there's no bluecreen, nothing in the Event Viewer indicates what is happening, ctrl+alt+del doesn't work, reset button doesn't work. I can only power down the PC by pressing the power button. The PC doesn't hang during use, like browsing or gaming.

PC is at the stock settings, with the latest drivers. No OC, no uV, stock RAM timings. But I've got all the CPU power states enabled in UEFI, meaning up to C10, C1E, SpeedShift. I ran RAM tests for a few hours - no errors. I've got the latest UEFI update from MSI. The PC is not overheating - idle temps are: CPU 25C, GPU 32C. All other temps in HWInfo are very good. Both SSD and HDD are in very good condition.

The PC passes every test I throw at it with a very good score - Cinebench R20/R15, CPU-Z bench, 3DMark FireStrike/TimeSpy, Unigine Superposition, Corona, V-Ray, Witcher 3, Civilization 6.

I do not exclude a software error. Maybe the latest Win 10 is a reason, or maybe the latest Radeon drivers. Also, how do I know if my PSU supports all the CPU power states?

What I'm currently trying is I disabled PCI-E energy savings in Win 10, but I'm yet to see if it helps.

THE SPECS:

- the latest Win 10 2004
- i5-8600K stock
- XFX RX 590 FatBoy
- 2x 8GB G.Skill 2666MHz CL19
- MOBO: MSI B360M PRO-VDH with the latest UEFI
- PSU: SilentiumPC Vero L2 600W

Comment: Have you checked your hard disks for SMART errors?

Comment: Yes, they are completely fine.